# Using jQuery .load() to pass a parameter to and call a php function

Tags: php, jquery

This is the jQuery .load function I have.  What I want to do is run the php function with a passed value from the jQuery.  I think I just don't understand how to pass values with jQuery to the server.  Do I perhaps need to use .get or .post?  Please advise.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#scotland").click(function() {
    $("#Main").load('thumbs.php #Main', $path=./scotland);
  });
});
```

php div that the jQuery script targets.

```
<div id="main">
<?php
function thumbnailload($path)
{
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open folder");
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {

if(ereg("(.*)\.(jpg|bmp|jpeg|png|gif)", $file)){
echo "<a href='$path/$file'><img class='thumbnail' src='$path/thumbs/thumb_$file' alt='$file'></a>";
}
}
closedir($dir_handle);
}
thumbnailload($path);
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is usually in early to have this kind of problem, not knowing how to interact with a client-side language (JavaScript) to a server-side (PHP). But let's go!

For the page "thumbs.php" receives a parameter, you must send the data via GET or POST.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#scotland").click(function() {
        $("#Main").load('thumbs.php', {'path': 'scotland'});
    });
});
```

thumbs.php

```
<div id="main">
    <?php
        if(!empty($_REQUEST['path'])) { // i used $_REQUEST because it receives the data from POST or GET.
            $path = $_REQUEST['path'];
            $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open folder");
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {
                if(ereg("(.*)\.(jpg|bmp|jpeg|png|gif)", $file)) {
                    echo "<a href='$path/$file'><img class='thumbnail' src='$path/thumbs/thumb_$file' alt='$file'></a>";
                }
            }
            closedir($dir_handle);
        } 
    ?>
</div>
```

The method .load() in jquery uses a GET request type if the data is not passed. In our case, I am passing data ( {'path': 'scotland'} ), so the request is of type POST.

**Useful links**:

- [jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
- [PHP.net - Variables From External Sources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

I hope I was helpful =]

Answer (score 1):

change you jQuery script to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#scotland").click(function() {
    $("#Main").load('thumbs.php #Main', {'func': 'thumbnailload', 'path': './scotland'});
  });
});
```

and change PHP code to:

```
<div id="main">
<?php
$func = $_GET['func'];
switch($func){
    case 'thumbnailload':
       thumbnailload($_GET['path']);
    break;
}

function thumbnailload($path)
{
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open folder");
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {

if(ereg("(.*)\.(jpg|bmp|jpeg|png|gif)", $file)){
echo "<a href='$path/$file'><img class='thumbnail' src='$path/thumbs/thumb_$file' alt='$file'></a>";
}
}
closedir($dir_handle);
}
thumbnailload($path);
?>
</div>
```

for ref: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I changed the files like you mentioned but the switch case is never true, and thumbnailload is never called, it then hits the second function call after the function definition which results in the or die result because $path is never defined.  Any insight?

Comment: why the case isn't true we are passing it's value here `'func': 'thumbnailload'` ?